# Matrix for which $A^\ast A = 1$, but $A A^\ast \ne 1$ (or reversed)

Tags: matrices

Title says it all: unitary matrices have the property that $AA^\ast = A^\ast A=1$. I want to find an example as in the title. For finite matrices, this doesn't seem to work out. How can I find an infinite-dimensional matrix satisfying the expression in the title?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For finite matrices this does still work. You just can't use square matrices. For example consider the isometry that embeds $\mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^3$ defined as
$$
V = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $V^* V = I_{\mathbb{C}^2}$ but $VV^* \neq I_{\mathbb{C}^3}$.

Comment: I was indeed too focused on square matrices. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be the shift operator on the Hilbert space $H=l^\infty$ with basis $e_0$, $e_1$, $e_2$, ... which is determined by
$$
Te_k=e_{k+1}\ .
$$
Then its adjoint $T^*$ is determined by $T^*e_k=e_{k-1}$, with the convention that $e_{-1}=0$. Or explicitly,
$$
T^*e_k=
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{ for } k=0\ ,\\
e_{k-1}&\text{ for } k>0\ .
\end{cases}
$$
To see this, it is enough to check $(T^*e_j,e_k)=\delta_{j-1,k}=\delta_{j,k+1}=(e_j,Te_k)$. Now compute $T^*T$ and $TT^*$ (especially on $e_0$).